# use a single nonce in three different nonce field

Tags: theme-development, ajax

i want to use a single nonce in three different form (login, register, lost password). But I am not sure how to use nonce in wp_localize_script( $handle, $object_name, array() ). In here $handle parameter i will use external js file handler and inside that file I'll write code for three different form (login, register, lost password) and for each form I'll use three different nonce.

Here is my code:

**1 -  three separate html file (login-form.php, register-form.php and lostpassword-form.php)**

```
<form id="login" action="login" method="post">
    <?php wp_nonce_field( 'ajax-login-nonce', 'login_nonce_token' ); ?>
</form>
<form id="register" action="register" method="post">
    <?php wp_nonce_field( 'ajax-login-nonce', 'register_nonce_token' ); ?>
</form>
<form id="lostpassword" action="lostpassword" method="post">
    <?php wp_nonce_field( 'ajax-login-nonce', 'lostpassword_nonce_token' ); ?>
</form>
```

**2 - in my scripts.js file**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    // login
    $('form#login').on('submit', function(e){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: ajax_login_object.ajax_url,
            data: {
                'action': 'ajaxlogin', // wp_ajax_nopriv_ajaxlogin
                'login_nonce_token': ajax_login_object.nonce, // wp_localize_script()
        });
    });

// register
$('form#register').on('submit', function(e){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: ajax_login_object.ajax_url,
        data: {
            'action': 'ajaxregister', // wp_ajax_nopriv_ajaxregister
            'register_nonce_token': ajax_login_object.nonce, // wp_localize_script()
    });
});

// register
$('form#register').on('submit', function(e){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: ajax_login_object.ajax_url,
        data: {
            'action': 'ajaxlostpassword', // wp_ajax_nopriv_ajaxlostpassword
            'lostpassword_nonce_token': ajax_login_object.nonce, // wp_localize_script()
    });
});
});
```

**3 - and my class-wp-ajax-popup files code**

```
public function __construct() {
    add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'ajax_login_modal_init' ) );
}

public function ajax_login_modal_init() {
    if ( ! is_admin() || is_customize_preview() ) {
        wp_register_script( 'ajax-login-script', get_parent_theme_file_uri( 'admin/assets/js/scripts.js' ), array( 'jquery' ), filemtime( get_parent_theme_file_path( 'admin/assets/js/scripts.js' ) ) );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-login-script' );
    }

    wp_localize_script( 'ajax-login-script', 'ajax_login_object', array(
        'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
        // HOW TO USE NONCE HERE. I write this way, is it right?
        'nonce'    => wp_create_nonce('ajax_new_none')
    ) );

    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ajaxlogin', array( $this, 'ajax_login_jquery_callback' ) );
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ajaxregister', array( $this, 'ajax_register_jquery_callback' ) );
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ajaxlostpassword', array( $this, 'ajax_lost_password_jquery_callback' ) );
}

public function ajax_login_jquery_callback() {
    check_ajax_referer( 'ajax_new_none', 'login_nonce_token' );
}

public function ajax_register_jquery_callback() {
    check_ajax_referer( 'ajax_new_none', 'register_nonce_token' );
}

public function ajax_lost_password_jquery_callback() {
    check_ajax_referer( 'ajax_new_none', 'lostpassword_nonce_token' );
}
```

I write this code based on codex and other online documents.

My question is - **how i'll use nonce in wp_localize_script and in scripts.js file? Is all my code correct?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass multiple nonces with `wp_localize_script()` by just including them as separate properties in the `ajax_login_object` object.

```
wp_localize_script( 'ajax-login-script', 'ajax_login_object', array(
        'ajax_url'                 => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
        'login_nonce_token'        => wp_create_nonce( 'login_nonce' ),
        'register_nonce_token'     => wp_create_nonce( 'register_nonce' ),
        'lostpassword_nonce_token' => wp_create_nonce( 'lostpassword_nonce' ),
) );
```

Then in your JS, use the correct one from your localize object as the value for each request, and use the same `_ajax_nonce` name for the field name.

```
data: {
    'action': 'ajaxlogin',
    '_ajax_nonce': ajax_login_object.login_nonce_token,
}

data: {
    'action': 'ajaxregister',
    '_ajax_nonce': ajax_login_object.register_nonce_token,
}

data: {
    'action': 'ajaxlostpassword',
    '_ajax_nonce': ajax_login_object.lostpassword_nonce_token,
}
```

Then in your AJAX handler, use the names you gave them when creating them with `wp_create_nonce()` for the first argument, and the field name as the second argument:

```
check_ajax_referer( 'login_nonce', '_ajax_nonce' );

check_ajax_referer( 'register_nonce', '_ajax_nonce' );

check_ajax_referer( 'lostpassword_nonce', '_ajax_nonce' );
```

The second argument needs to be the field name we used in JavaScript, which is `_ajax_nonce`, but this is the default value (which is why we used it), so we can leave it out, if we want:

```
check_ajax_referer( 'login_nonce' );

check_ajax_referer( 'register_nonce' );

check_ajax_referer( 'lostpassword_nonce' );
```

Comment: Thank you very much @jacob. You describe everything too much clearly. What about **wp_nonce_field()**? Are those correct that way i write? If those are right that means nonce field's first parameter will be _wp_localize_script_'s **array key**. Am I right?

Comment: `wp_nonce_field()` is just a function that creates a `<input type="hidden" name="_wp_nonce">` field with the nonce as its value. You'd use it if you needed to send a nonce as part of a form submission in PHP. Regarding the array key of `wp_localize_script`, this has nothing to do with the nonce. The only time you use this is to access the value in JS. Notice how I gave it a different name in my answer, so that you can see which is which.